# insert values into two tables at the same time - one to one relationsship

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, one-to-one

I have two mysql database table. They have one-to-one relationship between each others. They are empty. I can't insert value to anyone. Each one has a foreign key of another one. I'm planning to insert value to them in the same time. But, I didn't find which sql query is necessary. What is your offer?
Thanks

one-to-one relationship example:

```
student: student_id, first_name, last_name, address_id
address: address_id, address, city, zipcode, student_id
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in your table design. Please add the table structure of both tables.

Comment: student_id is primary key of the student table and foreign key of the address table.
address_id is primary key of the address table and foreign key of the student table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1 to 1 table relationship, that doesn't mean you have to put their PK on each other, instead people usually decide which FK goes to another table and that's all. From what you did, that shows Many to Many table relationship, and the right schema would be creating a new table that has FK to those 2 tables.

Details:

If 1 student can have MANY address and 1 address can be lived by MANY student, then the schema is:

```
student: student_id, first_name, last_name, address_id
address: address_id, address, city, zipcode, student_id
student_address: student_id (FK), address_id (FK)
```

If 1 student can have only 1 address and 1 address can be lived only by 1 student, then the schema is:

```
student: student_id, first_name, last_name, address_id, address, city, zipcode
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need address_Id in the student table.  What if the student is homeless? What if a student has more than one addresss? He/she might have a mailing address a local address in the college town, and a home address.
And even for students with only one address, you can get that address by querying the address table using student_Id.

```
 Select * From addresses where student_id = [Whatever his/her id is]
```

Even more generally, multiple students might live at the same address.  Neither table should have a FK to the other. There should be an address table, with `addressID`, a Student table with `studentId`, and a third table that contains just  `studentId` and `addressId` to indicate the association between one student and one address.  The PK for this table should be composite (using both `StudentId` and `AddressId`)

Answer (score 0):

That is not how MYSQL works.  It sounds like your database design needs to be reworked.  You can't have a circular foreign keys like that.  **You can only insert into one table at a time.**

Looking at your tables, the student should have Student Id as the primary key, and a foreign key relationship to the address table.  The student Id in the address shouldn't be in that table.

Comment: (*" You can't have a circular foreign keys like that."*) That's show MySQL works you mean. SQL has deferred constraints which work just fine in DBMS that have implemented them (like Oracle and Postgres.) But I agree with the database design needing to be reworked.

Comment: student_id is primary key of the student table and foreign key of the address table.
address_id is primary key of the address table and foreign key of the student table as well.